# vis-network's hierarchical layout has too much whitespace

Tags: visnetwork

Here is my code:

```js
this.network = new vis.Network(container, data, {
  layout: {
    hierarchical: {
      direction: 'UD',
      sortMethod: 'directed',
    }
  },
  physics: {
    hierarchicalRepulsion: {
      avoidOverlap: 1,
    }
  }
});
```

and the result is:

[image: The result]

Why are these edges in the center so long?

Nodes & Edges: https://pastebin.com/7MMszDuC

P.S. vis-network 7.5.2

Answer (score 0):

use this in network properties:

```
layout: {
    hierarchical: {
      ...
       shakeTowards: "roots",
    }
},
```